# Restoring rebuilt system from its Time Machine backup after an SSD failure?

Tags: time-machine

Following an SSD failure I need to restore my user directories and some other miscellaneous config files. When I first restarted with a fresh OS (Catalina) I tried to use migration assistant to restore my files from my time machine backup. Migration Assistant found the disk (a wired NAS) and the time machine partition on the disk, accepts the password, requests and accepts the encryption password. It then shows "Backup Loading".

It is at this point that things don't work as expected/documented. What I expect to happen at this point is that the backup loads, the continue button becomes live, and I'm able to continue to select what it is I'd like to restore. Instead, however, the "Backup Loading" notation remains for as long as I've let the system sit (several hours).

I then bypassed the migration assistant and continued through the first boot I tried running Migration Assistant manually, but hit the same wall. Using the System Preferences time machine panel I connected time machine to the existing backup. When I go to "Enter Time Machine" it shows no backups present.

At this point, if I go to `/Volumes/Time Machine Backups` I can see the `Backups.backupdb` folder and inspect the full history of my backups. They are all present. How can I get Time Machine to recognize that there is a backup there to access?

Comment: First welcome to Time Machine hell! “Instead, however, the "Backup Loading" notation remains for as long as I've let the system sit (several hours).” Yup. That happens sometimes. Can I ask: Have you installed an OS on the new SSD in the Mac? Or are you attempting to do this via recovery mode?

Comment: The system was repaired under apple warranty and came back with a freshly installed OS. 
Separately, while making a fresh attempt to inform TM about the disk (nothing like hitting your head against the wall just one more time), TM began a backup. I stopped it, but not before the two minute countdown. In the Volumes folder, underneath the folder with the system name, there is now a Backups.backupdb folder there is now a 2020-06019-195700.inProgress folder. All the other backup folders appear untouched.

Comment: “The system was repaired under apple warranty and came back with a freshly installed OS.” I would contact Apple then directly and explain what you are going through. I’m sure you are not the first person in a situation like this.